# Map a Scala tuple example

Tags: scala

In the following example where l1 and l2 are list of integers, I'm wondering why this produces an error?

```
l1.zip(l2).map(_ => { if(_._1 > _._2) 1 else 2 } )
```

It complains that it misses parameter type for expanded function. Why is the underscore not allowed here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Each individual `_` expands to an expected input. The *nth* `_` is interpreted as the *nth* argument. You'll find that this

```
l1.zip(l2).map(x => { if(x._1 > x._2) 1 else 2 } )
```

works instead. Or using pattern matching

```
l1.zip(l2).map{case (x1,x2) => if(x1 > x2) 1 else 2}
```

(thx to [Kigyo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2650807/kigyo))

Comment: Another way: `l1.zip(l2).map{case (x1,x2) => if(x1 > x2) 1 else 2}`

Comment: Of course. I've integrated that into the answer. Thx

Answer (score 1):

Approaches based in for comprehensions which bypass the central problem here,

```
for ( (a,b) <- l1 zip l2 ) yield { if (a > b) 1 else 2 }
```

and

```
for { (a,b) <- l1 zip l2 
       v = if (a > b) 1 else 2 
    } yield v
```